# detecting finger valleys with Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, biometrics

I have a binary image of the hand like that:

[image: hand binary image]

I have to write a Matlab function that detects the valley between two fingers.
The parameters are the binary image and the coordinates of the two finger's tips.

I'm new in image processing and I don't know how to start.

Comment: There are so many approaches. You could try and find some using google and then ask more specific questions.

Comment: I know the location of one point in the black region between the two fingers. My idea was to start with this point and search the valley (the search area is delimited by white pixels and by the X coordinate of the two finger's tips). But I don't know how can I search the valley point.

Comment: Look into: "convexity defects", that is a method that is typically used when dealing with this kind of hand-images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to isolate the black area between the two input points, and then find the highest point in this connected component.
You can try the following approach (you may need to tweak some of the parameters, but it should be a good start).

```
I = rgb2gray(imread('<your path>'));

%input parameters - points which represents two finger tips.
x1 = 408; y1 = 441;
x2 = 454; y2 = 373;

%binarize image  
I = im2bw(I);

%noise reduction - close holes
I2 = imclose(I,strel('disk',10));

%draw a line between p1 and p2
ind = drawline([y1 x1],[y2 x2],size(I));
lineMat = zeros(size(I));
lineMat(ind) = 1;

%adds the line to the image
I2 = I2 | lineMat;

%finds a point in the middle of the line
[lineY, lineX] = ind2sub(size(I),ind);
midX = lineX(ceil(length(ind)/2));
midY = lineY(ceil(length(ind)/2));

%finds a point which resides in the connected component which is between
%the line and the two finger. 
xSeed = midX;
ySeed = midY -5;

%perform imfill operation, starting from (xSeed,ySeed),
%in order to find the conected component in which the point (xSeed,ySeed)
%resides.
diffMat = imfill(I2,[ySeed xSeed])~=I2;

%finding the highest point in this connected component
[Y, X] = ind2sub(size(diffMat),find(diffMat));
minInd = find(Y==min(Y),1,'first');
yValley = Y(minInd);
xValley = X(minInd);

%presents result
imshow(I);hold on;
plot(x1,y1,'r.','MarkerSize',20);
plot(x2,y2,'r.','MarkerSize',20);
plot(xValley,yValley,'b.','MarkerSize',20);
```

*draw line function is taken from [drawline webpage](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/15374-drawline/content/drawline.m).

Final result (input points in red, output point in blue).
[image]

Answer (score -1):

It's just the algorithm, but all these function certainly exist in MatLab:

1. Compute the convex hull
2. Compute the difference: Convex Hull minus the original shape. Then you have all the valleys you are looking for, plus some small patterns.
3. Connected components labeling.
4. Delete the small components. Then you have all the valleys between the fingers.
5. Then you can select the one you want using the fingertip coordinates.